# Pythonic way of replacing element i with ```[i,i,i]``` in NumPy array quickly?

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, numba

I've seen a lot of questions with answers on how to efficiently replace elements of a NumPy array with specific things, such as "1" or something, if they satisfy certain conditions.

I wish to replace all the elements in a 2D NumPy array with an array of themselves, i.e. element `i` is turned into an element `[i,i,i]` or perhaps `[f(i),g(i),h(i)]` for some functions `f(x),g(x),h(x)` which I specify. How can this be done pythonically (and preferably, in a way agreeable to Numba)?

Comment: So the result should be 3D?

Comment: Yeah. It's maybe easy to guess that this just a way of me taking a 2D array of scalars and convert it into something I want for an RGB image. I tried to think of some way of doing it by creating some new array ```b=np.empty(list(np.shape(a))+[3])``` and then doing something with it, but I don't know enough NumPy to go from there.

Comment: I'm also curious because vectorized function `def foo(x): return x,x,x` applied on an array returns a 3-item tuple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `np.repeat`:

```
a = np.repeat(np.arange(30).reshape(10, 3)[..., np.newaxis], 3, axis=2)
print(a.shape)
print(0, 0, :)
```

Output:

```
(10, 3, 3)
[0 0 0]
```

Comment: Add a new axis in the last position with `np.newaxis`, and then repeat the source array thrice along the new axis.

Comment: Pretty impressive what you can do with NumPy!